# How to increase the buffer size for a program's arguments on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I made a C# program that gets a list of files as arguments through the Windows Explorer context menu and process them (basically it's just right click on a list of files and select that program to process them).

I read the arguments with this code:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (args.Length > 0)
{
    //processing
}
```

Apparently Windows has a limit on the number of arguments (2048 bytes). So, how could I pass lots of files to this program and avoiding that limit?

Comment: Will they necessarily select all the files in a single folder? (In this case you could pass the directory name). Will there be any predictable pattern in which files they'll select (e.g. all the text files from directories a, b, and c)? (Maybe a regex or something?)..

Comment: The files are always from the same folder, but they could be arbitrarily selected (e.g. the first, the second and the last file). Not pattern at all.

Comment: Do they select all of the files at once (i.e. control-click kind of thing) or one at a time? If they select them one at a time then you could use that to build a file with a list of the names of the file (otherwise that would obviously just be pushing the problem back another step).

Comment: You can implement a [DropTarget handler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183) which lets you receive an arbitrary number of files.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: Thanks. I will check that article. By the way, I've heard about your contributions to Windows.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: They're selected with CTRL-click or with SHIFT-click or with CTRL-A (for all files). The thing is that the files are already selected when the program is run.

Based on the comment below by SomeUser I need to save the list of these selected files to a temporary text file that it will be loaded by that program.